# Test admin rights within PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, system-administration, admin-rights

Whats the best/easiest way to test for administrative rights in a PowerShell script?

I need to write a script that requires administrative rights and want to know the best way to achieve it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is the little function I have in a security module:

```
function Test-IsAdmin {
    try {
        $identity = [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
        $principal = New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal -ArgumentList $identity
        return $principal.IsInRole( [Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator )
    } catch {
        throw "Failed to determine if the current user has elevated privileges. The error was: '{0}'." -f $_
    }

    <#
        .SYNOPSIS
            Checks if the current Powershell instance is running with elevated privileges or not.
        .EXAMPLE
            PS C:\> Test-IsAdmin
        .OUTPUTS
            System.Boolean
                True if the current Powershell is elevated, false if not.
    #>
}
```

Answer (score 19):

In Powershell 4.0 you can use [requires](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847765(v=wps.630).aspx) at the top of your script:

```
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator
```

Outputs:

> The script 'MyScript.ps1' cannot be run because it contains a "#requires"       statement for
>   running as Administrator. The current Windows PowerShell session is not running as Administrator. Start Windows
>   PowerShell by  using the Run as Administrator option, and then try running the script again.

Comment: When you paste `#Requires -RunAsAdministrator` on the top of a script in the PowerShell ISE nothing happens...

Comment: This is great, but using Right mouse button > Run with PowerShell just closes the script right away. `Read-Host` as the next line doesn't help. How to deal with this when trying to directly run a script?

Answer (score 6):

Here it is directly:

```
$isAdmin = ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole(`
        [Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")
```

Answer (score 5):

FYI, for those folks that have the [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com) installed:

```
PS> Test-UserGroupMembership -GroupName Administrators
True
```

This cmdlet is a bit more generic in that you can test for group membership in any group.

Comment: Just curious, does this just check if the user in the group or does it also check if they are running with all privilege tokens (elevated)?

Comment: @AndyArismendi if you are not elevated this will return false even if the user is in the Administrators group on a UAC enabled system. That's because the process has just a "standard" user token.  If the process is elevated then this returns true.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this url: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/05/11/check-for-admin-credentials-in-a-powershell-script.aspx

I didn't test it but the summary seems to state what you are looking for: "Learn how to check for administrative credentials when you run a Windows PowerShell script or command."